# How to call the ajax page in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have  two files **demo.php** and **post.php**. How can I do in single
 page instead of two page.

**demo.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").on('submit',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: data
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="Us">Us</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="textbox" name="other" id="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country"  style="visibility:hidden;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
        $Country = $_POST['other'];
        echo $Country;
    }
?>
```

How can I use the **post.php** data in  **demo.php** without passing data from one page to another.

Answer (score 3):

Change the url of your ajax

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "demo.php",
      data: data
 }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```

And add this in your demo.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
        $Country = $_POST['other'];
        echo $Country;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few personal observations:

- the first one it's in the approach: I don't think it was a bad idea to have two separate files. This is not really a good optimization. Now you want a single file to handle a GET request and POST in two different ways (one for AJAX one for normal POST in case you want your javascript to degrade gracefully.
- you might want to remove that "onchange" attribute. Look into the concept of [**Unobtrusive JavaScript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for why this is good practice
- never trust user input: always sanitize and validate appropriately
- bellow is a version of your file rewritten. Notices I've re factored the `onChange` with something more maintainable and I'm using JS to make the initial hiding of the input and submit button. This way if JS is disabled the user can still add countries.
- in order to determine how the post was triggered I pass an extra flag `ajax=1` to the post.

  ```
  <?php
      $country = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'other');
      // Ajax
      if (isset($_POST['ajax']))
      {
          echo 'Successfully added country: ' . $country;
          exit();
      }
      // normal post
      else
      {
          echo $country;
      }
  ?>
  ```

  Dynamic Form
      
      
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#country').on('change', hideStuff);

  ```
      // hide the buttons to add extra option
      $('#other, #submit').hide();

      function hideStuff()
      {
          var select = $(this);
          var flag = select.val() === 'other';

          $('#other, #submit').toggle(flag);
      }

      $("form").on('submit',function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          data = $(this).serialize() + "&ajax=" + 1;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: $(this).data('url'),
              data: data
          }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
      });
  });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post" data-url="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <select id="country" name="one">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                          <option value="India">India</option>
                          <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                          <option value="Us">Us</option>
                          <option value="other">Other</option>
                      </select>
                      <input id="other" type="textbox" name="other">
                      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country">
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

that's very easy, just paste the below code on to the upper code.

And remove the jquery ajax call.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Form</title>


</head>
<body>

<form action="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other'){this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="Us">Us</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="textbox" name="other" id="other" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country"  style="visibility:hidden;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
        $Country = $_POST['other'];
        echo $Country;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url into `demo.php` and use the below one along with `exit();`,

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $Country = $_POST['other'];
        echo $Country; 
       exit();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you change the url of $ajax

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "demo.php",
  data: data
 }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

and then change your "demo.php"

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on('submit',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post.php",
                data: data
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        });
    });
   </script>

  </head>
   <body>
   <?php 
         if(isset($_POST['other'])) {
       $Country = $_POST['other'];
       echo $Country;
        }
      else{
        ?>
   <form>
  <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='other')  {this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden';this.form['submit'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="Us">Us</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
              </select>
               <input type="textbox" name="other"id="other"style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Country"style="visibility:hidden;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
  </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").on('submit',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var yData = $(this).serialize();
                $.post('demo.php', {action:"other",yourData:yData}, function(msg) {
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
if($_REQUEST['action']=="other")
{
    $country= $_REQUEST['yourData'];
    echo $country;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you but I don't understand what "data" is. Make sure it is a field or the variable which is supplying value that is required for the page.

```
$("form").on("submit",function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                cache : false,
                url : "post.php",
                data : {
                    data : data
                },
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#content').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```